# How to change individual cell text colour when values are entered/changed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I would like to make cells change text colour when numbers are entered but the existing numbers in column need to remain the same colour unless I change them.
In the image you can see I have rows and columns that are pre-populated with text. Whenever a change is made, I'd like the text font colour (only of the A Column) to go from black to red.

E.g. if I want to change number 02 to another number, once the new number is entered that new number changes text colour to red automatically, BUT the numbers below it, 03, 04, 05, 06 will remain black until I change them - if necessary.

I have tried conditional formatting but that changes all cells to red when text is inputted (incl. the cells that are already there...)

http://postimg.org/image/doqokmd6x/

Answer (score 0):

Add some vba code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 1 Then
  Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 End If
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your requirement.

```
Public strOldValue As String

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     'Assign previous value to a variable
    strOldValue = Target.Value

End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strNewValue As String
    'Check for first Column
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        'Assign New Value
        strNewValue = Target.Value
        'Compare Old value and New Value
        If Trim(strOldValue) <> strNewValue Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes myself to the above VBA, here is what I was looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If
End Sub
```